# Capital text with space. What kind of text format is this?

Tags: text, unicode, encode

I've got a list of songs that look like this.

> ＧＩＦＴ〜白〜（冬恋／君の歌をうたう）【完全生産限定盤】

The latin letters GIFT here looks odd and I can't figure out how to make it read like a normal text. For example if you copy this word, it doesn't have a space in-between the letters or anything but seems to be in a different text format.

Can someone help me how I can convert this into normal text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Unicode characters.
For example, the 'G'  is

> Unicode Character 'FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G' (U+FF27)
> UTF-8 (hex)    0xEF 0xBC 0xA7 (efbca7)

see [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff27/index.htm)

You can copy the string to Notepad++ and then convert it into Hex code (Extensions/Converter/ASCII->HEX)

and get `EFBCA7EFBCA9EFBCA6EFBCB4` for the word 'GIFT'

Then serach for "Unicode EFBCA7" to find the above information.

This can be converted into normal latin characters. For example in .Net there is the [Normalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=net-5.0) function:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unicode:");
        String text = "ＧＩＦＴ";
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        foreach(var b in bytes)
            Console.Write("{0:X} ", b);

        Console.WriteLine("\nASCII:");
        String text2 = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
        Console.WriteLine(text2);
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text2);
        foreach(var b in bytes)
            Console.Write("{0:X} ", b);
    }
}
```

try it on [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Qhb8Z)
This will print out:

> Unicode:
> ＧＩＦＴ
> EF BC A7 EF BC A9 EF BC A6 EF BC B4
> ASCII:
> GIFT
> 47 49 46 54

Probably there are similar functions in other languages too. Now you know what you're looking for.

The search term "convert unicode FULLWIDTH LATIN" will help you.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454529/convert-latin-characters-from-shift-jis-to-latin-characters-in-unicode)

When you can't find a function for that, you can also just do your own conversion, after all the character code is just an offset to the normal ASCII/UTF-8 latin character set. See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486551/javascript-function-to-convert-utf8-string-between-fullwidth-and-halfwidth-forms).

Comment: @Craftwerk: you're welcome. I added a few words about conversion back to normal, as that was also a part of your question.